# Capture Contents of Awesomium Web Control

Tags: vb.net, awesomium

I want to capture contents of WebControl as a image. I search all the web and couldn't found a way. Could you please suggest me a way to do it with VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of Awesomium you are using, but have a look at the [SaveToPNG](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_BitmapSurface_SaveToPNG_1.htm) method.

There is also a good tutorial [here](http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/).